# Textarea return key Listener called twice in iOS Apppcelerator?

Tags: ios, keylistener, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile, uitextarea

I have write a function for textArea return key listener in Titanium appcelerator iOS.

```
$.returnText.addEventListener('return', function(e) {
$.replyMessageTxt.blur();
console.log("click return key");
callbackend() // here will call back end via Api call
});
```

Meet Following problems:

- it called twice when i click return key.
- it send a text to back end with **'/n'** or **'%0A'**

i dont know why it's happened. can some one help me to resolve this bug!

Thank You

Comment: If possible can you share more code over here so it make easy to check , What exactly happens .

Comment: Hi Dharmik thanks for you reply, return key event execute once only but its prints console msg twice so only confuesd. and the next one is also resolve by sent the plain text to backend before i have sent json encoded data.